# Unable to "quit" the latest version of Viber

Tags: 22.04, kill, viber

I installed the latest version (18.2.0.2) of **Viber** from the `.deb` package provided at https://www.viber.com/en/download/

After installing the new version, I noticed that there is no way to terminate the Viber application using GUI: The "Quit" option for the application menu does nothing. As in the previous versions, closing the main window does not terminate the application (it continues to run on the background); however, contrary to previous versions, using the right-click (system) menu of the application and selecting **Quit** *does not terminate the application*.

When I ran  it from command line and then tried to "quit" the application, I see this message on the terminal window:

```
qt.qml.context: qrc:/Resources/QML/MainWindow.qml:68:5 Parameter "close" is not declared. Injection of parameters into signal handlers is deprecated. Use JavaScript functions with formal parameters instead.
```

To terminate Viber I have to `kill` it using `-1`.

Is there a practical way to fix this, so that Viber users do not have to resort to command line to stop (and restart) Viber whenever they need?

Comment: I do not use the application, but does the [Alt]+[F4] keyboard shortcut work? That should close the application 

Comment: No. The window is closed, but the application continues running on the background. (I updated my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viber version 20.3.0.1 finally works properly in Ubuntu 23.04.

The .deb package is provided at the official Viber website.

Comment: Thanks. As you said, version 20.3.0.1 finally works properly. (Until they break it again!)

Answer (score 7):

That's a known bug*. Something changed in Viber tray icon handling. Right click menu could be broken on KDE Plasma as well.

You can workaround it with such steps:

1. Install dbus-x11 package (which contains CLI utility dbus-launch)

   sudo apt install dbus-x11
2. Kill viber instances

   pkill -f -9 viber
3. Try to launch it on a terminal with dbus-launch

   dbus-launch /opt/viber/Viber
4. Check if right click works. It's not perfect but works from few tries
5. Modify Viber launcher

   a) On the original Ubuntu (with GNOME) you can install menulibre package for that

   b) You can do it manually on a terminal

   sudo nano /usr/share/applications/viber.desktop
6. Log Out and Log In

*https://github.com/flathub/com.viber.Viber/issues/4#issuecomment-1280456307

Comment: Thanks. I tested and it acts as you described. So, that's an improvement for me!

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm!